# Logtalk: meta::map, lambda expression and access to private method

Tags: logtalk

I think this is a scope related problem. If I have a rule on my object like this:

```
:- public(new/2).
:- mode(new(+list, -object_identifier), one).
new(Args, Instance) :-
    self(Self),
    create_object(Instance, [instantiates(Self)], [], []),
    Instance::process_arguments(Args).
```

I find this works fine if I do this dance:

```
:- object(name, instantiates(name)).
```

I don't fully understand why this is necessary but I suspect it is linked to my actual problem, which is that if I have your standard Prolog loop in my object, like so:

```
process_arguments([Arg|Args]) :- process_arg(Arg), process_arguments(Args).
process_arguments([]).

process_arg(Arg) :- ::asserta(something(Arg)).
```

I find this use of `::asserta` puts the facts in the right namespace (on the newly-created instance). However, if I get witty and replace the body of `process_arguments/1` with this lambda expression:

```
process_arguments(Args) :- meta::map([Arg]>>process_arg(Arg), Args).
```

then I wind up with my facts being added to the parent class and shared by all the instances. If I replace it with this:

```
process_arguments(Args) :-
    self(Self),
    meta::map([Arg]>>(Self::process_arg(Arg)), Args).
```

then it works, but I have to make `process_arg/1` a public rule when I'd rather not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start first with your snippet of code above where the object `name` instantiates itself. In doing this, you make `name` its own class. Nothing wrong where. In languages that support meta-classes, such as Smalltalk and Logtalk, making a class its own meta-class is a classical way of avoiding an infinite regression. See, for example the Wikipedia entry on meta-classes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass). See also the "reflection" example in the Logtalk distribution. By making the object `name` instantiate itself, it plays both the role of an instance (as it instantiates an object) and the role of a class (as it's instantiated by an object). If you defined `name` as a stand-alone object, i.e. an object with no relation to other objects, it would be compiled as a prototype.

Now to your question. In Logtalk, meta-predicates (such as `meta::map/2`) are called in the context of the *sender*. If the `process_arguments/1` predicate is defined in `name`, then the execution context (including the value of *self*) will be `name`. Thus, the clauses for `something/1` will be asserted in `name`. Your workaround (by using the built-in method `self/1`) works as expected but it does forces you to declare `process_arg/1` public predicate. This is a bug in the stable Logtalk version as it should also work by declaring the `process_arg/1` predicate protected or private (as the *sender* is `name` and the predicate is declared in the *sender*). For example:

```
:- object(name,
    instantiates(name)).

    :- public(new/2).
    :- mode(new(+list, -object_identifier), one).
    new(Args, Instance) :-
        self(Self),
        create_object(Instance, [instantiates(Self)], [set_logtalk_flag(dynamic_declarations, allow)], []),
        meta::map({Instance}/[Arg]>>(Instance::process_arg(Arg)), Args).

    :- private(process_arg/1).
    process_arg(Arg) :-
        ::asserta(something(Arg)).

:- end_object.
```

I will push the bug fix into the publicly available Logtalk development version later this week. Thanks for driving my attention to this bug.

Comment: Pushed the bug fix into the publicly available Logtalk development version (r6516).

Comment: The bug fix is included in the new Logtalk stable release, 2.44.0, released earlier today.

Comment: Would "Closure = {Instance}/[Arg]>>(Instance::process_arg(Arg)), meta::map(Closure, Args)" also work? I see in the source code that you expand meta::map/2.

Comment: @j4nbur53 The lambda expression is compiled when the library meta-compiler is used. But as the variable `Instance` is only known at runtime, the closure `::/2` itself cannot be compiled to use static binding. Writing instead `Closure = {Instance}/[Arg]>>(Instance::process_arg(Arg)), meta::map(Closure, Args)` as you suggest also works, of course.

Comment: @j4nbur53 Objects can be static or dynamic. A source file can define both. "Instance" is a *role* that an object can play. See http://logtalk.org/manuals/userman/objects.html#objects_kind When the object argument of a message sending call is know at compile time, static binding is usually possible (assuming that the `optimize` flag is turned on).

Comment: @j4nbur53 Only dynamic objects can be abolished http://logtalk.org/manuals/refman/predicates/abolish_object_1.html

Comment: @j4nbur53 That imitation only existed on Logtalk 2.x. Documentation fixed on the git repo.